# How to use CodeSniffer in Phpstorm using Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

Is there a way to configure PHPStorm with CodeSniffer when CS is installed on Vagrant?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no -- ATM **only local** installation is supported.

Watch/vote this ticket to get notified on progress: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22674

Answer (score 0):

There is a way now to use Code Sniffer from Vagrant in PHPStorm now.

See the picture below for more details.

[image]